# How to Find Missing number in Sequence using mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
   SELECT a.blog_id+1 AS start, MIN(b.blog_id) - 1 AS end
   FROM wp_blogs AS a, wp_blogs AS b
   WHERE a.blog_id < b.blog_id
   GROUP BY a.blog_id
   HAVING start < MIN(b.blog_id);
```

It's working for me thank you for this post and i need brief explanation about this query

Answer (score 3):

Without much experience in writing SQL queries, it's hard to understand by simply staring it down. A good approach is to "rebuild" it to understand what each step does.

Start with some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_blogs
    (`blog_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO wp_blogs
    (`blog_id`)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (6),
    (7),
    (9)
;
```

Now we rebuilt it step by step. Start with the `JOIN`. (I don't like joining in the `where` clause, so I've rewritten it, but it works the same):

```
SELECT
a.blog_id as aa,
b.blog_id  as bb
FROM
wp_blogs a
JOIN wp_blogs b ON a.blog_id < b.blog_id
ORDER BY aa, bb /*added the ORDER BY for readability in the output*/
```

This has the following output:

```
| aa | bb |
|----|----|
|  1 |  2 |
|  1 |  3 |
|  1 |  6 |
|  1 |  7 |
|  1 |  9 |
|  2 |  3 |
|  2 |  6 |
|  2 |  7 |
|  2 |  9 |
|  3 |  6 |
|  3 |  7 |
|  3 |  9 |
|  6 |  7 |
|  6 |  9 |
|  7 |  9 |
```

As you can see the table is joined to itself, and on the right side only the rows are displayed that are greater than the left side.

Now we continue with the `GROUP BY` to collapse the groups on the left side. Whatever column you have in the `SELECT` clause, but not in the `GROUP BY` clause, you have to apply an aggregate function on it. Otherwise it's not clear which row for each group should be displayed. You have to tell MySQL, that you want the smallest number in the group. This can be done like this:

```
SELECT
a.blog_id as aa,
MIN(b.blog_id) as bb
FROM
wp_blogs a
JOIN wp_blogs b ON a.blog_id < b.blog_id
GROUP BY aa
ORDER BY aa, bb
```

Result is:

```
| aa | bb |
|----|----|
|  1 |  2 |
|  2 |  3 |
|  3 |  6 |
|  6 |  7 |
|  7 |  9 |
```

What we are interested in now, are the rows where the number on the right is not the number that is followed immediately after the number on the left. We filter on this with the `HAVING` clause, not with the `WHERE` clause, because we're dealing with groups here. In your query this is done with `HAVING start < MIN(b.blog_id)`. `start` refers to the alias set in the `SELECT` clause for `a.blog_id+1`.
In other words, we add 1 to the value in the left column. If this is equal to the value on the right side, don't display the row.

So the result of this is:

```
SELECT
a.blog_id + 1 as aa,
MIN(b.blog_id) as bb
FROM
wp_blogs a
JOIN wp_blogs b ON a.blog_id < b.blog_id
GROUP BY aa
HAVING aa < MIN(b.blog_id)
ORDER BY aa, bb

| aa | bb |
|----|----|
|  4 |  6 |
|  8 |  9 |
```

`bb` is the number that is found in the table. That's why in your statement in the `SELECT` clause again 1 is subtracted from `MIN(b.blog_id)`. The final query is:

```
SELECT
a.blog_id + 1 as aa,
MIN(b.blog_id) - 1 as bb
FROM
wp_blogs a
JOIN wp_blogs b ON a.blog_id < b.blog_id
GROUP BY aa
HAVING aa < MIN(b.blog_id)
ORDER BY aa, bb

| aa | bb |
|----|----|
|  4 |  5 |
|  8 |  8 |
```

Hope it's clear now :)
Play around with it in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/137e2a/7/0) if you like

Answer (score 3):

**Plan A**  Partial solution (building on tombom's example):

```
SELECT a.blog_id AS Missing_before_this
    FROM      wp_blogs AS a
    LEFT JOIN wp_blogs AS b  ON b.blog_id = a.blog_id - 1
    WHERE b.blog_id IS NULL;
```

It will erroneously flag the first blog_id.  And it will not say how many ids are missing in the gap.

**Plan B**  A more complete solution involves adding an extra column that has sequential numbers, then doing a self-join on this new column (with a similar -1 trick).  The delivers the value before and after each gap.

**Plan C**   Create a table with all numbers in a suitable range, then use a `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` to see which `blog_id` values are missing.  (Note to MariaDB users:  Such a sequence is trivial to do.)

Comment: As a minor addition to Plan A. You could also use `(a.blog_id - 1) AS missing`. That will get you missing number.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the missing number from the Table. This works for me

```
SELECT distinct(l.membership_no + 1) as nextavabile
from Tablename as l
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tablename as r on l.membership_no + 1 = r.membership_no
WHERE r.membership_no is NULL and l.membership_no is not null order by nextavabile asc;
```

If Any issues let me know.
Thank you guys.

Comment: This answer does not appear to add value beyond the answers which have already been provided.  The answer is additionally in response to a much older question.